# I'm having an issue trying to recover information from mongodb

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm trying to recover some collections from my database, and I'm not pretty sure why it isn't displaying as it should.

Thanks for any feedback !

// Here's my router's code:

```
    router.get('/add', (req, res, next) => {
    var categories = db.get('categories');
    categories.find({},{},(err, categories)=>{
        res.render('addpost', {
            'title': 'Add post',
            'categories': categories,
            'errors': []            
         });
       })  
    });
```

// And here's my ejs file:

```
    <label>Categoria:</label>
                <select name="category">
                    <% for (var i=0; i < categories.length; i++) { %>
                    <option value="<%= categories[i].title %>"><%= categories[i].title %></option>
                    <% } %>
                </select>
```

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaVNO.jpg)
  [print2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQTKK.jpg)

Comment: What is it actually displaying/what is the error?  It would help if we knew what was going wrong so we can better answer the question.  For example, is it not getting the data from mongo right or is it getting the data and not showing it correctly?

Comment: It is getting the data but not showing it correctly I guess, because the page loads normally, but there are no options when you click it

Comment: what is it showing?  is either the value or display information for the option displaying?  Are they all blank or are there no options showing up?

Comment: They are not showing up, the values are empty.

Comment: Here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaVNO.jpg

Comment: I would verify that categories is actually an array of objects then.  It doesn't look like the for loop is runs.  And the only issue I see popping up is if categories.length is zero

Comment: Oh i see, so i'ma look for a diferent way of doing it i guess. Thank you !

Comment: Maybe, I would just verify what kind of data categories actually is.  The problem appears to be with the fact Categories may not be an array so I would actually verify what categories is

Comment: It seems to be a JSON file (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQTKK.jpg)
Sorry for bothering so much, i'm very newbie yet

Comment: No problem, Ill add in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

categories, which you retrieve from the find() call is actually a JSON object and not an array.  You either need to convert it into an array or loop through the json using the .forEach call